# Variable outside of FB API fetch value returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, facebook-graph-api, fetch, es6-promise

I'm trying to loop the URL in FB API so that I can retrieve all the photos without paginating it (for photo searching), but when i try to define the value for "after", it always returns undefined. This is the code:

```
let next;
for (let ctr=0; ctr<albumcount; ctr++) {
  let url = '';
  if (ctr>0) {
    console.log(ctr, next)
    url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/${val}?fields=photos.limit(100)%7Bimages%2Cname%2Clink%7D&after=${next}&access_token=${access_token}`;
  } else {
    url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/${val}?fields=photos.limit(100)%7Bimages%2Cname%2Clink%7D&access_token=${access_token}`;
  }
  fetch(url)
  .then(results => {
    return results.json();
  }).then(data => {
    next = data.photos.paging.cursors.after;
  });
}
```

I've been trying multiple things but "next" always returns undefined. How do I return a value for "next".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

fetch/AJAX is **asynchronous**. So the whole loop will be completely finished BEFORE you even get to the first fetch callback. You can use a recursive function for that, or (even better) [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
let result = await fetch(url);
```

Also, you should not use the album count for the loop - just loop as long as there is a "next" link in the response.

Comment: what exactly did you try? how did you try it? you should know exactly how asynchronous js works, and how to deal with promises. it´s important for async/await (and js in general).